# Pointers in C with chars, cant call the value

Tags: c, pointers

This might just be the dumbest question, but i havent found any explanation when it comes to char, just when it comes to int, which i can manage.
However, i got this huge problem, i've pointed the adress of my pointer to a char and from that char i want to print out the value.
This is how my code looks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *pn) {

    char text[64];
    char nei;
    text[64] = &pn;

    printf("%s\n", *text[64]);
}

int main()
{
    function("Hello");

    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

I can't figure out whats wrong with it to be honest. Why cant I put a `*` in front of `text[64]`, since thats how you print the `value`, correct?

Comment: text[64] is out of bounds! The lines `text[64] = &pn;` and `printf("%s\n", *text[64]);` appears to be terrible.

Comment: **char *pn** is a pointer to hold address of single character but not a collection of characters

Comment: @Philly It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you changed `char` to `int` throughout, the program would remain very broken.  It should not compile at all.  You need to go back and restudy pointers — what is shown here strongly indicates you've misunderstood the topic.

Comment: By Stackoverflow's guidelines this appears to be a reasonably well formed  question.  I wonder why the down votes?  Is it possibly because they cost the down voter nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*' has meaning when applied to a pointer. Applied to a char, I'm not sure what it would do. So, no, putting a * in front of text[64] is not how you print the value.

In your code text is a 64 byte long array of char. Valid indexes into it are 0 to 63.

The expression text[64] refers to memory you don't have access to, or may be a reference into one of your other automatic variables. text[64] is beyond the end of the array.

```
void function(char *pn) {    
    char text[64];
    char nei;
    text[64] = &pn;      /* <- this won't work */
    strcpy(text, pn);    /* <- probably will work, may overflow text if string at pn is too long */

    printf("%s\n", *text[64]);  /* <- this won't work */
    printf("%s\n", pn);         /* <- probably will work */
    printf("%s\n", text);       /* after strcpy above, will likely work */    
}
```

Comment: " Applied to a char, I'm not sure what it would do. " <- it should generate a compiler error.

Comment: Good answer, immibis. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both * and [ ], and also text[64] is out of bounds as its said in comment. You can use function strcpy to copy one string to another.

Comment: Yes. He is derefferencing already derefferenced variable which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`char text[64];` declares `text` as an array of 64 characters.

`printf("%s\n", *text[64])` makes no sense, because:

1. `text[64]` points to the character *after* the end of the array; i.e. `text[63]` is the last character in the array.
2. `*text[64]` attempts to dereference the 64th item in the `text` array. But each item is not a pointer, but a character.

Perhaps you meant `&text[n]` where `n` is a number between 0 and 63, which would be a pointer to a character within the array, and hence a string. In C a string (what `%s` expects) is a pointer to a character, and the string is that character and all following up until a `NUL`.

This bit of your question is unclear:

> Why cant I put a * in front of text[64],

(answered above)

> since thats how you print the `value`, correct

I have no idea what that bit means. As per the above, `%s` expects a `char *`, i.e. a pointer to a character.

Answer (score 0):

*Why cant I put a * in front of text[64]*

*You can!*  but not the way you have tried to do it.

For example, in a *declaration*,  `char *text[64];` would be used to create an array of strings, each 64 bytes in length. And would require allocation of memory using  malloc()`or`calloc()`, ***or*** an initializer such as:

```
char *text[64]={"this is a string1","this is string2"};
```

Which creates an array of 2 strings, each with 64 bytes (although only partially used), which could be used like this:

```
printf("%s\n", text[0]);  
printf("%s\n", text[1]);
```

*since that's how you print the value, correct?*  (referring to:`printf("%s\n", *text[64]);`)

No.

The argument `char *pn` refers to a *single string*.
If you want to copy this argument to the local variable:
First, change the line:

```
text[64] = &pn;
```

to

```
if(!pn) return; //test and leave if pn is null pointer
strcpy(text, pn);
```

Then just use:

```
 printf("%s\n", text);
```

to print the line

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy the contents of the pointer *pn to the    character array text then you better use strcpy() function.

```
strcpy(text,pn);
```

will let you copy the contents.

You trying to print out the contents of the array. you can't use the * and  [] together.
In case of a array 
for example

```
char text[64]
```

as you have mentioned in your code

```
printf("%x",text);
```

will print the start of the allocated memory where the array lies.
when you do text[0] the start of the allocated memory address will be added with 0 and the contents of that memory will given back.
This is how an array work
Now if you are to use a dereferencing operator * then *text will give the 0th element of the array

```
 *(text + 1)
```

will give you the second element of the array and so and so forth.
one more thing you can't use

```
printf("%s",text);
```

as the value that you are passing to the function is not a string but a character array as it does not have '\0' at its end.